# window.history.replaceState misbehaving adding new entry

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to change dynamically the URL without adding a new entry in the browser history. To do that, I want to use the history.replaceState.
The point is: If I try in some sites it works, but if I try it in my website or stackoverflow, it adds a new history entry.
This is causing the back button to "misbehave" when used.

To reproduce this issue, open firebug in this page and write

```
history.replaceState({},"","/asd")
```

And check that a new history entry is added.

Am I doing something wrong? I want to change the browser url but do not add a new history entry so the back button works correctly. How can I fix this?

sorry: forgot a very important info: browser FF 21.0 and Chrome v. 27.0.1453.110 m

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, '/asd')
```

Comment: In this page? It does not work for me. what browser are you using? Im using browser FF 21.0 and Chrome v. 27.0.1453.110 m

Comment: that's weird.. I'm using the same browsers and it's ok.